# Java applet throws multiple exception when handling a mouseReleased event

Tags: java, exception, applet

I'm trying to make a simple applet where you can draw simple shapes (the shape and the color are selected via right-click menu) by dragging on the screen. The shape is actually drawn on mouse release. Now my code:

```
public void init()
    {
        addMouseListener(this);
        addMouseMotionListener(this);

        figuri=new Vector();
        culori=new Vector();

        popup=new PopupMenu();
        Menu figura=new Menu("Figura");
        popup.add(figura);


        for (int i=0;i<numeFigura.length;i++)
        {
            MenuItem mi=new MenuItem(numeFigura[i]);
            mi.setActionCommand(numeFigura[i]);
            mi.addActionListener(this);
            figura.add(mi);
        }

        Menu culoare=new Menu("Culoare");
        popup.add(culoare);

        for (int i=0;i<numeCuloare.length;i++)
        {
            MenuItem mi=new MenuItem(numeCuloare[i]);
            mi.setActionCommand(numeCuloare[i]);
            mi.addActionListener(this);
            culoare.add(mi);
        }

        indexFiguri = 0;
        indexCulori = 0;

        mouseClickedStr = "";
        mousePressedStr = "";
        mouseDraggedStr = "";
        mouseReleasedStr= "";
        drawModeStr     = "Modul de desenare "+numeFigura[indexFiguri];
        drawColorStr    = "culoarea "+numeCuloare[indexCulori];

        this.add(popup);
}
public void paint(Graphics g)
    {

        Graphics2D gg;
        gg=(Graphics2D) g;

        String drawMouseStr;
        String drawMode;

        drawMode = drawModeStr+" "+"folosind "+drawColorStr;

        drawMouseStr = "";

        if(mouseClickedStr.length()>0)
            drawMouseStr = mouseClickedStr+x_click+" "+y_click;
        if(mousePressedStr.length()>0)
            drawMouseStr = mousePressedStr+mouseX1+" "+mouseY1;
        if(mouseDraggedStr.length()>0)
            drawMouseStr = mouseDraggedStr+mouseX2+" "+mouseY2;

// This is the call that throws the exception
            if(mouseReleasedStr.length()>0){
            Color culoare;
            switch (indexCulori){
                case 0: {culoare = Color.RED; break;}
                case 1: {culoare = Color.GREEN; break;}
                case 2: {culoare = Color.BLUE; break;}
                case 3: {culoare = Color.YELLOW; break;}
                case 4: {culoare = Color.BLACK; break;}
            }
            switch (indexFiguri){
                case 0: {figuri.addElement((new Line2D.Double(x_click,y_click, mouseX3-x_click,mouseY3-y_click))); break;}
                case 1: {figuri.addElement((new Rectangle2D.Double(x_click,y_click,mouseX3-x_click,mouseY3-y_click))); break;}
                case 2: {figuri.addElement((new Ellipse2D.Double(x_click,y_click,mouseX3-x_click, mouseY3-y_click))); break;}
            }
        }


        if(drawMode.length()>0)
        {
            gg.setColor(Color.black);
            gg.drawString(drawMode,10,20);
        }

        if(drawMouseStr.length()>0)
        {
            gg.setColor(Color.black);
            gg.drawString(drawMouseStr,10,40);
        }

        for(int i=0;i<figuri.size();i++)
        {
            gg.setColor(culoare[((Integer)culori.get(i)).intValue()]);
            gg.draw((Shape)figuri.elementAt(i));

            if (culori.get(i)!=null){
                gg.setColor(culoare[((Integer)culori.get(i)).intValue()]);
                gg.fill((Shape)figuri.elementAt(i));
            }
        }
    }

//And the function declaration.
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent me)
    {
        mouseX3=me.getX();
        mouseY3=me.getY();
        mouseReleasedStr= "Mouse released at ";
        mouseClickedStr = "";
        mousePressedStr = "";
        mouseDraggedStr = "";

        repaint();
    }
```

The exceptions thrown are:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-1" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Array index out of range: 0
    at java.util.Vector.get(Vector.java:694)
    at events.paint(events.java:218)
    at java.awt.Container.update(Container.java:1801)
    at sun.awt.RepaintArea.updateComponent(RepaintArea.java:239)
    at sun.awt.RepaintArea.paint(RepaintArea.java:216)
    at sun.awt.windows.WComponentPeer.handleEvent(WComponentPeer.java:310)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4727)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2099)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4481)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:643)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:84)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:602)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:600)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:87)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:98)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:616)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:614)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:613)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:269)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:184)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:174)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:169)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
```

Thank you for your patience and your help!

Comment: A few tips (not an answer): use a package for your classes (e.g. `package com.flolancu;` at the top of your file, and create a directory `com/flolancu/` for your java files) and stick to the naming conventions, such as class names with capitals (`events` -> `Events`)

Comment: @TheNail: +1. What's more, even with the issues mentioned in the answers below, I guess the code will still have significant problems. (I see that there are two variables named `culoare` about; that's _bound_ to be confusing!) Any one of the _excellent_ Java IDEs would probably highlight many of these simpler issues straight off…

Comment: As I've stated, I merely modify an existent applet, it's downright confusing to me too. What's more, I have to use a crappy IDE (JCreator) to see the console while the applet is running (I don't know how to do that in Netbeans/Eclipse). Thank you all for your support anyway! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to say for sure without line numbers in your code, but there are only a few cases where you call `Vector.get` so this looks like the culprit:

```
for(int i=0;i<figuri.size();i++)
    {
        gg.setColor(culoare[((Integer)culori.get(i)).intValue()]);
        gg.draw((Shape)figuri.elementAt(i));

        if (culori.get(i)!=null){
            gg.setColor(culoare[((Integer)culori.get(i)).intValue()]);
            gg.fill((Shape)figuri.elementAt(i));
        }
    }
```

You are iterating over `figuri` but also looking up values in `culori`. It looks like you have added an item to `figuri` that does not have a corresponding entry in `culori`.

Check and make sure that whatever code you have that adds items to `figuri` also adds the right items to `culori`.

Comment: I forgot I had two Vectors to deal with. The assignment is to actually modify an applet based on my prof's backbone and I'm still struggling to understand it.
Thank you so very much for your answer and sense of observation :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't see where you guarantee that the two `Vector`s are the same length; I'm guessing that in reality `culori` is shorter than `figuri` (indeed, that it is empty).
What is more, you're using a test for `null` on the result of `culori.get(i)` *after* you have cast it to `Integer` and called a method on it. That will not work in the way you expect!

You might want to consider not using `Vector` but instead using `ArrayList`, and you *definitely* want to write your code so as to be compliant with Java 5 (i.e., use generics) if at all possible. (After all, it's been out over 7 years now…)